# Unable to get response using node curl package on Nodejs

Tags: node.js

I'm using node curl to make a call to a WS. I wrote a simple function that just issues a request and I'm logging the response. This is how my server.js looks:

```
var http = require('http');
var curl = require('node-curl');
var config = require('./config');

var cfgObj = new config.config();
function start(port) {
    function onRequest(request, response) {
        console.log("Request received");
        var options = {
            VERBOSE: 1,
            RAW: 1
        };
        curl.debug = 1;
        curl.setDefaultOptions(options);
        curl('www.google.com', function(err) {
            console.log(this.body);
        });
    }
    http.createServer(onRequest).listen(port);
}

cfgObj.getConfig(null, function(data) {
    start(data.port);
});
```

cfgObj just contains the port number. It connected to the host properly and I even got HTTP 200 OK response:

> [cURL 1] receive 2242 bytes
>   [cURL 1] receive succeeded.

But in the end, it says:

> Bus error: 10

What does this mean?

The control never calls the function where I'm printing this.body. I even tried using http request but that gives me "socket hang up" error.

I have been unable to debug this issue. Any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`node-curl` is broken, when I try to use it on my Mac I get the same error:

```
[2]    34539 bus error  node test.js
```

(a bus error is an error which occurs when a program tries to write to an invalid memory location)

Here's a replacement for `node-curl`: https://github.com/mikeal/request